# Passing parameters for dynamic SQL in a function

Tags: postgresql, functions, dynamic-sql, postgresql-10, parameter

I am trying to create a function which will dynamically create a unique table name, populate the table with a result set returned from another function, and return the table name to the caller. In outline, it looks something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_result_table(
    _param1 integer[],
    _param2 text[])
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    _table_name TEXT;
    _select TEXT;
BEGIN
    _table_name := '_XYZABC_' || replace(current_date::text,'-','_') || '_' || 'ZXCVBN'; -- not the real code
    _select := '(select * from some_other_function(_param1, _param2))';
    execute 'create table some_schema.' || _table_name || ' as ' || _select;
    return _table_name; 
END;
$BODY$;
```

The code is accepted, and it appears to be forming the command correctly as

```
execute 'create table some_schema._XYZABC_2020_10_07_ZXCVBN as (select * from some_other_function(_param1, _param2))'
```

but when I try to execute it with:

```
SELECT return_result_table(ARRAY[0,1,5,19],ARRAY['AA,'BB','CC'])
```

I get the error

> ERROR:  column "_param1" does not exist

> LINE 1: ...ect * from return_result_table(_param1...

It *appears* that the code is trying to substitute in the value of a column (of what?) rather than using the parameter.

How can I prevent this translation happening, so that I can pass the parameters through into the called function?

Comment: I replaced "procedure" with "function" in your question, as you are obviously using one. Note the difference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/194811/3684 (Though it doesn't make a lot of difference for your core problem.)

Answer (score 3):

To make it work dynamically, do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_result_table(_param1 integer[], _param2 text[])
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _table_name text := to_char(current_date, '"_XYZABC_"YYYY_MM_DD"_ZXCVBN"');  -- equivalent, but still not the real code
   _select     text := $$(select * from some_other_function($1, $2))$$;  -- !
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE some_schema.%I AS ', _table_name)
         || _select
    USING _param1, _param2;
   
    RETURN _table_name; 
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=581c2a3c559cf952ea3c04bd9311a129)*

This [passes parameters as *values* to `EXECUTE` with the `USING` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN), which is cheapest and safest.

`$N` (`$1` and `$2`) in the string passed to `EXECUTE` refer to appended arguments, not to function parameters like it would in SQL code outside of `EXECUTE`. (Ordinal numbers are in sync only by chance.)

Note this [restriction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in
> `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` commands. In other
> statement types (generically called utility statements), you must
> insert values textually even if they are just data values.

The manual is a bit fuzzy there. The above command [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) *is* just such a utility statement, but parameter passing still work because the `SELECT` statement is evaluated on its own before results are passed to `CREATE TABLE AS`.

`format()` is instrumental to make it simpler and safer, too.

The used format specifier `%I` preserves the name as given (case sensitive) adding double quotes as needed automatically. (No SQL injection possible.)

Note that I only use nested dollar-quoting to fix the currently broken syntax highlighting of the site. Else, it can just be:

```
  _select     text := '(select * from some_other_function($1, $2))';  -- !
```

There are quite a few related answers with more details here on dba.SE. [Try a search for `[postgres] [dynamic-sql] format code:EXECUTE code:USING`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3684%20%5Bdynamic-sql%5D%20format%20code%3AEXECUTE%20code%3AUSING)

Prominently:

- [How to use function parameters in dynamic SQL with EXECUTE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159424/how-to-use-function-parameters-in-dynamic-sql-with-execute/159534#159534)

Also:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)